# Lengthy SQL stored procedure with tables storing more and more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, normalization

This question applies to stored procedures written in SQL-92
i.e. Oracle PL/SQL, SQL Server T-SQL or DB2 SQL

I'm maintaining an 11000 line stored procedure.
I find that by the end of the stored procedure I need to report out 80 columns of data.

There are 3 distinct phases in this stored procedure.

1. Data Gathering  (copying data from the live tables into the stored procedure intermediate tables)
   I need to do data gathering for consistency because the LIVE data (i.e. in the member table) at line 30 might have changed by the time the stored procedure execution gets to line 10,000
   Commit state atomicity is maintained here (no commit until all the data needed is copied over)
2. Calculation (lots of SQL, complicated enough so that Cursors or Views will not do the job)
3. Writing back to permanent tables (invoices, AR, payments)
   Commit state atomicity is maintained here (no commit until all the data needed is copied over)

The "intermediate" tables are only used in the stored procedure.
They are indexed for joins down the line but do not have
PK/FK referential integrity  constraints or unique indexes
as these would slow down execution considerably in addition
to pointing back to LIVE data (that is in flux)

When you get to 80 columns of data that you need to report by the end of a stored
procedure you run up against RDBMS limitations (index limits, memory limits,
SQL join COST limits, out of control paging and data going to virtual
memory/swap when the DB thinks it should use HASH instead of using NESTED LOOPS)

I have normalized LIVE data (that gets written to and read from 24/7 by data entry users)

It occurred to me that the way to optimize the space taken up by intermediate tables
used in the stored procedure (at step 2) would be to find composite primary keys and assign
each a unique id (a surrogate PK) thereby referencing n columns with 1 column.  Then, I
would reconstitute this data at the end of step 2 and have it ready to
write back to at the start of step 3. This would add more processing to
step 2 but less data would get copied around. Also debugging would take
more steps (tracing back ids to actual data in the intermediate
table data after execution completes)

Has anyone run into this scenario with lengthy stored procedures?
Has anyone created a surrogate key (replacing a compound PK with a one-column PK) in
intermediate tables that are only used in stored procedures?

Has that paid off in terms of execution time and memory/space used during
execution?

Comment: Did you say eleven THOUSAND line stored procedure??

Comment: Each time you execute your sproc: What is the size of the volume of data that you are creating temporary tables for? Intuitively, an 11 000 line sproc sounds like a wrong approach. Could you write a C# app that juggled the required data in memory during the calculations?

Comment: @Simen S It actually doubles the DB size.  C# row by row processing just is not an option when the stored proc is already doing very complicated data processing in SQL (which handles blocks of data)

Comment: Creating a surrogate key (replacing a compound PK with a one-column PK) is not normalization. It's not even normalisation (in case you're British) :)

Comment: @n8wrl Yes, you read correctly. The requirements call for a lot of calculations (it's written for an insurance industry TPA) depending on a LOT of rating factors (a lot of counts, grouping, SQL functions, time calculations).  The input is not trivial and neither is the outcome.  Don't mean to start a language war but in SQL everything I need to do takes 1/2 the time to read and modify. It's concise. Everything is handled in blocks. It's declarative, it's clean and easy.  It would be unmanageable in C#.

Comment: @Tom H. My mistake. What I'm trying to do is not normalization.  I've updated the parent post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a few lenghty SProcs and I've always gone for an **Indentity** column surrogate key. Is it possible to rethink what's being done and create separate temp tables for each intermediate step?

I've had to do this in the past. At the end, I "***stitched***" all the separate temp tables into my final output.

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I'm thinking of doing.  In SQL Server it is the Identity column, in Oracle it is SEQUENCE, in DB2 it is AS IDENTITY GENERATED BY DEFAULT in IBM DB2.

Answer (score 2):

And I thought my 1400 line procs were long!

I can see where a surrogate key would be faster in the joins than the composite PK.  But with anything this complex, I think you would simply have to try both ways.

Can you reduce the 80 columns at all? I guesss I'm asking if you used select * with joins where the join fieds would be repeated in the query and could be dispensed with.

Comment: There aren't any repeated multiple-field joins apparent.  What it really comes down to is I need to find/build a tool that backtracks the SQL join criteria to previous select items and suggests surrogate primary keys.

Comment: All I can say is it seems like a reasonable thing to try, but you will have to carefully measure to see if there is a real performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try writing SSIS packages. Most of your calculations will be in SSIS memory w/o bothering database other than writing to temp tables.

You can break down your package as many pieces as you want and process will be more maintainable.

BTW, 11K sproc is insane... Can't help it, had to say that :-)

Comment: I had not thought of SSIS.  SSIS is meant for ETL operations etc. and converting stored proc to SSIS packages will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I know 11K declarative SQL is insane, but the alternative (22K,33K -- choose your imperative language here) is more insane. Imperative languages deal with data row by row and there's no way to debug data in the middle of a process. I need to see the leftover intermediate table data if there's a problem with the end result. I've done Pro*C, C#, C with embedded DB2 SQL calls, etc. They don't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to do data gathering for consistency because the LIVE data (i.e. in the member table) at line 30 might have changed by the time the stored procedure execution gets to line 10,000"

In Oracle you could look at DBMS_FLASHBACK (or SERIALIZABLE isolation level) for this level of consistency. Flashback queries might avoid you needing to copy all the data over.

I've done a similar exercise for a data migration - lots of temporary tables. One factor to check is that stats are gathered at appropriate points in time for the temporary tables. If those tables are normally empty then the stats might be screwing things up at the end.